# Missing video formatter for embedding media into ckeditor

Tags: 8, media

I installed the **media entity** module, the **video embed field** module and also the [**entity embed**](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed) module.

Then I created a media bundle for videos. Created a embed entity button for media and added it to CKEditor

I created a new video bundle entity with a link to a youtube video. When I visit the entity I see the embedded YouTube player and I can play the video.

So far so good. Now I like to embed this media entity into another entity (Content type "Article"). I can do this over the CKEditor button created before and I can also select the video media entity.

What's not possible is to render the entity as an actual video. The only options are *Label*, *Entity ID* and *Thumbnail*. But a **Video** formatter is missing.

[image]

Probably I miss something? A well hidden option to (un)check or even a module to achieve this?

Comment: This guy had an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912292/drupal-8-how-to-render-a-media-entity-in-the-wysiwyg-using-entity-embed-module